# installing oracle fusion middleware(11G) in windows 8(Formsweb.cfg location issue)

Tags: forms, fusion, oracle11gr1

I have installed Oracle 11g ( Oracle 11.2.0.1) database in windows 8 (64 bit processor) desktop successfully.For learning purpose,I tried installing Oracle 11G Forms and Reports.As a first step,installed Oracle fusion middleware( weblogic 10.3.6 ) and I used 64 bit JDK ( jdk 6- 1.6.0_35) for installation.After that,installed Oracle Forms & Reports (Oracle Forms 11.1.2.2)-All are installed in the same machine.I was successfully able to complete the installation and started developing basic form layout and successfully compiled it.But while running it in Firefox,I am getting Missing plug in error(Unable to find suitable plugin).By going through the page source info,I understood that it is pointing to different jdk version.(I have attached page source)

After reading so many posts,I understood that changing the parameters in formsweb.cfg file can make the difference.But while searching it ,I could find my formsweb.cfg in a different folder. MW_HOME/user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\config\fmwconfig\servers\AdminServer\applications\formsapp_11.1.2\config

I read from many posts that it is present in $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/WLS_FORMS/stage/formsapp/11.1.1/formsapp/config .In my case,instead of WLS_FORMS folder,it is appearing in Admin server.Is it causing the problem?I have 3 questions regarding this.

1. Why formsweb.cfg is appearing in different folder.
2. What changes need to be done in formsweb.cfg in order to point it to the correct JDK.
3. If I use 32-bit JDK,can this issue be resolved.

Please help me to resolve these issues.
Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Renuka

Comment: I get an error on OS Certification on Windows 8 while installing Forms and Reports although I was able to install WLS 10.3.6. Wondering if you faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is 4 months after the question was raised, I just saw it now after I solved the same problem for myself. Following is your answer and the fix:

1. Why formsweb.cfg is appearing in different folder.
   Ans: This is normal. The file formsweb.cfg is found in two locations in a weblogic 10.3.6, Forms 11.1.2.2 installation, unlike the Forms Services 10g. If you have do any chages, you might have to do in both the locations.
2. What changes need to be done in formsweb.cfg in order to point it to the correct JDK.
   Ans:  Although I did changes as described in this site, I am not sure, whether this had any role in fixing the problem. http://www.exploreoracle.com/2011/01/06/firefox-ie-crash-with-forms-10g-replace-jinitiator-with-jre/

   The problem was fixed only after I installed the plug-in JRE 7.60
3. If I use 32-bit JDK,can this issue be resolved.
   Ans: Of course 32 bit JDK will not fix the problem. You must use 64 bit JDK with your 64 bit OS.
   Note: You need to be careful about the supported version of JDK. In Windows 2008 Server R2 installation, the supported JDK is jdk1.6.0_30

Now here is the solution that fixed my problem:
You need to download plug-in JRE 7.60 and install it from http://java.com/en/download/chrome.jsp. It fixed my problem with both the Google Chrome and the Windows IE 9

Sincerely,
Mohammad Mazhar